# Libcurl authentication issues

Tags: c++, authentication, curl, header, libcurl

I'm trying to use libcurl in C++ to send requests to a url. When I set up the request in the command line with curl,  it seems to work fine:

```
curl -vvv -X POST -H "Authorization: <api key here>" -H "Content-Type:application/json" "<host>" --data-binary '<json data here>'
```

The response starts something like this:

```
> POST <host> HTTP/1.1
> Host: <host>
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: <api_key>
> Content-Type:application/json
> Content-Length: 80
```

So i can see the authorization is being sent properly.

When I try to do a similar thing in C++, using the libcurl C library, however, I don't notice the ">" in front of the request headers:

Code:

```
    struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Authorization: <api_key>");
    chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Content-Type:application/json");


    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "<host>");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "<json>");
    res =  curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

Response:

```
> POST <host> HTTP/1.1
Host: <host>
Accept: */*
Authentication: <api_key>
Content-Type:application/json
Content-Length: 97
```

So I'm not even sure if the headers are even properly being processed or received by the host.

Any ideas?

I get the following response:

```
{
  "message": "No authorization header given",
  "code": 401
}
```

Comment: The "> " are obviously inserted by the `curl` command itself. They are not part of `HTTP`.

Comment: That's true, but I assume it would be a hint given by the verbosity to what sets of parameters are sent as part of the request?

Comment: I have no idea what you meant by that. The curl command, obviously, prepends "> "  as a helpful indication that this is the sent part. That's it. Nothing more can be said about it.

Comment: Interesting, so is there anything suspect about the code itself? the API key works with curl but not with libcurl...

Comment: Good catch. This fixed it. Closing question.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect Header. Should be Authorization, not Authentication.

Comment: I have posted my comments as answer, its maybe usefull for other users.

Answer (score 0):

In your command line verbose output the header is named "Authorization: ". In your libcurl vebose output its "Authentication: ". Authorization != Authentication?

**Verbose output:**

Its only a different output format for verbose between command line and libcurl. The headers are sent. Same output format is used for example by php curl. Only first line has ">" and then all following headers has no ">". But they are all submited.

PHP curl verbose example output:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /XXX/api.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Accept: */*
Authorization: XXX
Content-Type: application/json

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 31 Dec 2018 20:12:51 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.34 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0i PHP/7.2.10
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.10
< Content-Length: 2390
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```